# set true value to a boolean variable not working - primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have this in my .xhtml

```
<p:inputSwitch value="#{object.attended}"
                    onLabel="yes"
                    offLabel="no">
                    <p:ajax event="change">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="event.currentTarget.checked"
                            target="#{object.attended}" />
                    </p:ajax>
                </p:inputSwitch>
```

This inputSwitch is inside a table... So, I manage a list of Objects which contents a variable name called attended, it's boolean.
What do I do in my beanManager y to set all attended variables to true...
But it doesn't work

```
public void setAttendetToTrueValue(){
    if(bean.getListObjects()!=null) {
        for(int i=0;i<bean.getListObjects().size();i++) {
            bean.getListObjects().get(i).setAttended(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think these parts should be like this

```
bean.object.attended
```

In the setProperty and switch tags to recognize the same object of the same class